# How to get an close event when the window is closed?

Tags: javascript

I'm integrating My application with Microsoft office 365 using Microsoft Graph API's.

Currently i am using upload/share/delete file API's.

i want to edit document online with office 365,
what i have done is using graph API's i'm uploading document to one drive creating link to share that document and opening the share url obtained from microsoft in new window to edit the document.

I am opening new window with share URL received from microsoft and once the user edit in new window closes that window i want to capture it and save the changes from cloud to my application

```
var new_window  = window.open('file_share_url_from_microsoft', '_blank','location=yes,height=780,width=1100,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');

//i want to capture close event when new_window is closed
```

is there anyway i can allow users to edit document in my application without opening in new tab..?(tried iframe but due to x-frame-options restricted to same-origin, it is not rendering in iframe)

is there anyway i can get the event when the edit window is closed by an user.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var new_window  = window.open('file_share_url_from_microsoft', '_blank','location=yes,height=780,width=1100,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
```

i couldn't find any solution to get close event after the new window is closed though , i've implemented with timer (where timer runs every "X" minutes and checks for the window is closed or not)
[REFERENCE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/closed)

```
var timeOut=null;

timeOut = setInterval(function() {

       if(new_window.closed) 
       {
       clearTimeout(timeout);

      /*logic after window closes*/

       }

    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using _parent will open in the same window, rather than a new one.

```
window.open('file_share_url_from_microsoft', '_parent','location=yes,height=780,width=1100,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
```

Comment: but user should stay on the application , users can edit in new tab/window still i'm not able to get the close event of an window though changed my logic to detect weather window is closed or not using "window.closed"  based on the flag i'm able to continue